# Maven project runs sql-maven-plugin executions from dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, sql-maven-plugin

**How can I configure my Maven `pom.xml` and/or `sql-maven-plugin` so that the unit test related DB executions I've specified in my dependency, `lib.example.jdbc`, don't get executed when building the `pom.xml` of my project `com.example.project`?** Currently when I run `mvn clean install` on the `pom.xml` for `com.example.project` I find that my SQL database has tables that were created in `lib.example.jdbc`. One obvious workaround is to use different properties for `mysql.database` in each `pom.xml` file but i feel the bigger problem is that the library's (dependency) db executions are being run in the test phase of the main project. I cant imagine this being correct since one can have hundreds of `pom.xml` dependencies with their own tests and db executions that shouldn't be run when building the final project.

**UPDATE: A Spring annotation was the culprit as discovered in my answer so I updated the question tags to reflect that.**

Here is the relevant sample from the `pom.xml` of `lib.example.jdbc`:

```
...
<groupId>lib.example</groupId>
<artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
<properties>
  ...
  <mysql.port>3306</mysql.port>
  <mysql.database>testDb</mysql.database>
  <mysql.user>root</mysql.user>
  <mysql.pass>password</mysql.pass>
</properties>
...
<build>
...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.44</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}/${mysql.database}?useSSL=false</url>
                <username>${mysql.user}</username>
                <password>${mysql.pass}</password>
                <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true-->
                <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-db</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}?useSSL=false</url>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <sqlCommand>create database if not exists `${mysql.database}`</sqlCommand>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And here is the relevant sample from the `pom.xml` of `com.example.project`:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
...
<properties>
  ...
  <mysql.port>3306</mysql.port>
  <mysql.database>testDb</mysql.database>
  <mysql.user>root</mysql.user>
  <mysql.pass>password</mysql.pass>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>lib.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.44</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}?useSSL=false</url>
            <username>${mysql.user}</username>
            <password>${mysql.pass}</password>
            <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
            <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true-->
            <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>drop-db-before-test-if-any</id>
                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}?useSSL=false</url>
                    <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                    <sqlCommand>drop database if exists `${mysql.database}`</sqlCommand>
                    <sqlCommand>create database `${mysql.database}`</sqlCommand>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: * I find that my SQL database has tables that were created in lib.example.jdbc* are you sure it is actually the `com.example.project` build that runs goals from your library project? That seems odd. Please provide the entire `com.example.project` build log with which you encounter the issue we'll be able to tell for sure (obfuscate any sensible element if required)

Comment: @PierreB. The problematic SQL is definitely getting executed when running the tests for `com.example.project` because i removed the DB, rerun my test and saw it back in there however the maven plugin was not the culprit. See my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, it seems the problem is not with the `sql-maven-plugin` but instead with the way a Spring annotation (@Sql) gets executed when running `com.example.project` tests from a test scoped configuration in `lib.example.jdbc`. Here is the class level annotation in `lib.example.jdbc` that was causing problems for me. I moved the code from my `schema.sql` and `data.sql` into my `pom.xml` `<sqlCommand>` block and it was no longer executed when testing `com.example.project`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = {"classpath:schema.sql","classpath:data.sql"})
public class DataDaoTest {
    ...

    @Test
    public void testRetrieval() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```